# Remove li text while leaving list-style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

I've got an unordered list with a list style using indented dots. I'd like to maintain those dots but remove the text from view. I originally guessed that I could simply set `text-indent:-999px;` but that removes the dot as well.

Any recommendations?

I know that it will work if the text inside the `li` is set to `&nbsp`, but that feels like cheating.

HTML

```
<div id="page_nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="showlink" id="show_one">PAGE ONE</li>
    <li class="showlink" id="show_two">PAGE TWO</li>
    <li class="showlink" id="show_three">PAGE THREE</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#page_nav ul{
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}
#page_nav li{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    float:left;
    font-size:3.5em;
}
```

Comment: Show us the HTML and the CSS, please!!!

Comment: Why is that cheating? If you make the color white, that'd be cheating.

Comment: Cheating because a screen reader couldn't say anything for it.

Comment: @technopeasant ... all he wants is the dot... why would screen reading care what's there anyhow?

Comment: Because it's an element on the page..

Comment: @technopeasant I should rephrase that... why would the user care. It's supposed to be hidden, so it shouldn't be read.

Answer (score 1):

`<li><span class="list_item">Item</span></li>`

`.list_item { display: none; }`

some context as to why you are hiding the text would help answer the question

Comment: This makes sense, and allows for future unhiding of the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to set the text to a `&nbsp;` then you could use [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) as follows:

Try this:

```
    $(function(){
        $("li.showlink").wrapInner("<span style='display:none'></span>");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a span inside the list item with display:block, and setting text-indent on the span?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.your_style').each(function()
{
  $(this).html($(this).html().toString().replace(/([^\.]+)/g,''));
});
```

this can help you

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is leave a blank `<li></li>` and that will display the dots without any text

Answer (score 0):

We need to know why you want this... the context...

Wo you want something to happen later that makes the text visibile? If so, you should put all the text within the `<li>` in a `<span>` that is `visibility:hidden` then upon wanting it to be displayed/read you should make it visible..

If you want to maintain the dot but lose the text... what would you want the screen reader to say? "dot?"..